# Passwordless SSH - no luck

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Need to get passwordless SSH access from my Macbook (client) to Ubuntu 22.04 server (server).
ssh_config on client and sshd_config on server remains original

All steps made on client:

1. Create key (no passphrase):

[image]

2. Copy this key to server:

[image]

3. Check ssh connection:

[image]
connection successful, but password still asked (((

What's wrong?

SOLUTION:

Add `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_macbook` to client's /etc/ssh/ssh_config

Comment: Please copy paste the text rather than images

Comment: Provide the configuration file for the OpenSSH Server, the client attempts to use the key you installed, but the server rejects it which suggests the server isn’t configured to look for that key.

Answer (score 2):

Your SSH client logs say that the client *is* offering the key, but the server is not *accepting* it. Which means the next step is to look at your **server's** `sshd` logs (`journalctl -S -1h`), as they would contain the reason that the key is being rejected – if not by default, then certainly after raising the log level (for example, adding `LogLevel VERBOSE` or `DEBUG` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` would be a good start).

In this case:

1. The key you've generated is **not the same key** you're trying to connect to. The key you've generated and uploaded is stored at `~/.ssh/id_macbook`, but you never told the SSH client to use that key when connecting – as you can see from the client logs, it's still using the default `~/.ssh/id_rsa` which is a completely different file.

   The sshd logs would say that the key being offered was not found in authorized_keys.

   Either specify the correct key using the `-i <file>` option when connecting (or via IdentityFile in ~/.ssh/config) or load your key into ssh-agent using `ssh-add <file>`.
2. Your `authorized_keys` file is set to be **world-writable** (possibly due to a weird `umask` setting on the server?), which most likely causes sshd to ignore the file for security reasons.

   The sshd logs would say that the permissions are "too open".

   Change it using `chmod` to be only accessible by the owner.

Comment: What I've seen in SSH verbose output - client never provides id_macbook identity to server. The simplest solution - add `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_macbook` as one of identites to /etc/ssh/ssh_config. It works!